# SharePoint Code Display Webpart

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, script

I'm wondering if there is a Code Display Webpart similar to what Microsoft have on thier Technet Galleries Pages as I am looking to implement a Script Versioning Display and would like to be able to display the Code on a SharePoint WebPart Page along with a section on the Script use and users etc.

I have tried to have a look around the web via Google however I have been unable to find anything that seems to match the requirements.

Ideally a user should be able to place this Web Part on the page and in the Web Part options link the Web Part to a script that is stored within a Document Library on the Site.

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you tried content editor webpart. Using that you can place HTML formatted text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a great Addin to Powershell ISE by Gary Lapointe that copys any script to into Html formatted text

http://www.thelapointes.com/blog/Falchion.PowerShell.CopyAsHtmlAddOn.zip

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can add code directly to SharePoint, rather you convert it to Html and then display it pages, blog, wiki etc.

I think you should check if their is any 3rd party tool who can convert you code into Html then you add that into your sharepoint.